# Moving files from a folder to a different folder using PortCMIS (C#)

Tags: c#, directory, alfresco, cmis, file-move

I have an alfresco database with a directory of folders and files.
I want to be able to move from one specific file to a different folder in the click of a button, so I used winForms for my process
You need to be Using the PortCMIS library in order to test these operations in C# code, there's also a version called "OpenCMIS" you can use if you are using Java.

'''

```
        private void btnMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        
        //Creates instance where I can access 
        //my private Alfresco sandbox database.
        parameters[SessionParameter.BindingType] = BindingType.AtomPub;
        parameters[SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = txtLink.Text;
        parameters[SessionParameter.User] = txtUser.Text;
        parameters[SessionParameter.Password] = txtPass.Text;

        SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.NewInstance();
        session = factory.GetRepositories(parameters)[0].CreateSession();
        
        //Error here, can't convert the string to
        //"PortCMIS.Client.IFolder or IDocument".
        IFolder sourcefolder = @"Rootfolder/folderWithFile";
        IFolder targetFolder = @"Rootfolder/folderToPutFileIn";
        IDocument doc = "fileTest.txt";

        //Supposed to move the document from source folder to
        //the target folder.
        doc.Move(sourceFolder, targetFolder);

    }
```

'''

[Example Picture of the Folder directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID8tq.png)

I also tried using "IFolder sourcefolder = session.GetRootFolder(*@"Rootfolder/folderWithFile"*);" but it still doesn't work, I'm unsure on what to do

My problem here is the variables I am calling "IFolder" and "IDocument". What should I do for it to do what I want? Do I need to find a way to convert the string directory into what i wants it to be? Is there a specific function that I should be using to help move these files?

Also, not to give excuses but I'm pretty new at using CMIS and Alfresco, and programming in general (I have almost 1 year of experience in coding at this point in time).
Which comes to say, if there is anything I said that might have been wrong, or something I'm doing that makes no sense, please do point it out so I can learn and get better as a result. And if you have any questions that you need answered in order to give a proper answer to my problem (necessary details and information) please do tell me about it.

Thank you !

Comment: Also, I'm using chemistry.apache as my only guide, here is a page on how to move objects :
https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/move-objects/index.html